# I want to send Buffer Object as response from API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an image file that is created on my backend(node) and I am trying to send that to the front end to display. I'm not exactly sure how to manage the data but when I console the variable that's holding the file I get this:

```
Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e2 02 28 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 ...
```

I'm making a GET request from the front end and I want to be able to grab the image that's created and then displayed on the frontend. Is something like this possible?

The other option I've come up is to use a database to store the file but I'm trying to avoid a db.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert Buffer Object to Base64:

```js
const bufferToBase64 = Buffer.from("Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e2 02 28 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 ...").toString('base64')
console.log(bufferToBase64)
```

Napkin (backend): https://www.napkin.io/n/a3fc1a9cf3654b35

2. Put String in `src` attribute of `img` tag:

```html
<img id="image" src="" />
```

```js
fetch('https://napkinhq.npkn.net/buffer-object')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.message)
    document.getElementById('image').src = `data:image/png;base64, ${data.message}`
});
```

CodePen (frontend): https://codepen.io/thomaswang/pen/oNWEmax?editors=1010

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this command

```
res.contentType('image/jpeg');
res.send(Buffer.from(data, 'binary'))
```

Comment: How would I receive it on the front end in order to display it?
I would set the content type from the axios request to 'image/jpeg' but how about turning that into actually displaying the image with an img tag?

Comment: Convert Buffer Object to Base64 string and then put this string in src attr of img tag